# Apportable No mtp compatible device

Tags: android, ios, apportable

I am currently experiencing a black screen after a successful compile with the following log entry:

No mtp compatible devices found: Falling back to slow path  
3691 KB/s (72457541 bytes in 19.167s) pkg: /data/local/tmp/TechBook-debug.apk  
Success  
am start -e EARLY_LIFECYCLE_DEBUG 0 -e NSUnrecognizedForwardingDisabled 1 -n corp.laserpros.com/com.apportable.activity.VerdeActivity  
Starting: Intent { cmp=corp.laserpros.com/com.apportable.activity.VerdeActivity (has extras) }

**Here is my debug report:**

LPIs-Mac-mini:LPI_TECH_APP_V1.3_BUILD_1.1.4_CONVERSION_THRU_APPORTABLE_OGL_ES2 MacUser$ apportable debug  
[1/10] Writing Build/android-armeabi-debug/TechBook/AndroidManifest.xml  
[2/10] Creating Build/android-armeabi-debug/TechBook/TechBook-resources.apk and R.java files  
[3/3] Building Build/android-armeabi-debug/TechBook/TechBook-debug.apk  
No mtp compatible devices found: Falling back to slow path
3650 KB/s (72457567 bytes in 19.385s)  
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/TechBook-debug.apk  
Success  
480 KB/s (9488 bytes in 0.019s)  
Using Xcode breakpoints v2  
am start -e EARLY_LIFECYCLE_DEBUG 0 -e NSUnrecognizedForwardingDisabled 1 -e  
 WAIT_FOR_ATTACH 1 -n corp.laserpros.com/com.apportable.activity.VerdeActivity  
Starting: Intent { cmp=corp.laserpros.com/com.apportable.activity.VerdeActivity (has extras) }  
Attaching to pid 2641  
Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0], There is no sepolicy file   
 Function: selinux_android_load_priority [1], There is no sepolicy version file  
 
 selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: seapp_contexts file is loaded from /seapp_contextsAttached; pid = 2641  
Listening on port 5039  
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.5-https://github.com/apportable/gdb Feb 20 2014 18:49:38  
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.  
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html  
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.  
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.  
This GDB was configured as "--host=x86_64-apple-darwin12.4.0 --target=arm-elf-linux".  
For bug reporting instructions, please see:  
http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/.  
Remote debugging from host 127.0.0.1  
warning: .dynamic section for "/Users/MacUser/.apportable/cache/devices/033f426d/libs/libxml2.so" is not at the expected address (wrong library or version mismatch?)  
warning: Could not load shared library symbols for 8 libraries e.g libdiag.so.  
Use the "info sharedlibrary" command to see the complete listing.  
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sys root"?  
0x400a6968 in ?? () from /Users/MacUser/.apportable/cache/devices/033f426d/libs/linker  
$1 = 1  
$2 = 0  
Breakpoint 1 at 0x65a965cc: file /Users/MacUser/Desktop/EPUB & APPS/Mobile App/AppleApp/NEW BUILD STRUCTURE/LPI_TECH_APP_V1.3_BUILD_1.1.4_CONVERSION_THRU_APPORTABLE_OGL_ES2/TechBook/main.m, line 15.  
Breakpoint 2 at 0x6335e6d8  
warning: Could not load shared library symbols for gralloc.msm8960.so.  
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?

Child exited with status 0  
GDBserver exiting  
[Inferior 1 (process 2641) exited normally]

**I noticed this while compiling [apportable load]:**

[316/319] Zipping Build/android-armeabi-debug/TechBook/TechBook debug.apk:/assets/ViewController.nib  
nwi_state: registration failed (1000000)  
[317/319] Zipping Bundle Build/android-armeabi-debug/TechBook/TechBook-debug.apk:/assets/MainStoryboard.storyboardc  
nwi_state: registration failed (1000000)  
[318/319] Zipping Bundle Build/android-armeabi-debug/TechBook/TechBook-debug.apk:/assets/MainStoryboard-iPad.storyboardc  
/Users/MacUser/.apportable/SDK/toolchain/macosx/zipbuilder/zipentry -o /Users/MacUser/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug/TechBook/storyboardc/MainStoryboard.storyboardc/5Bv-dv-le6-view-mTS-lg-CNz.nib.zipentry -i /Users/MacUser/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug/TechBook/storyboardc/MainStoryboard.storyboardc/5Bv-dv-le6-view-mTS-lg-CNz.nib --sha1

it goes on for a while with similar lines 
   
...MainStoryboard/...Info.plist --sha1  
...MainStoryboard/...instructionsViewer.nib --sha1  
...MainStoryboard/...home.nib --sha1  
...MainStoryboard/...contactus.nib --sha1

looks like it is having a hard time decrypting the storyboard nibs? could this because I haven't added them to the configuration.json file?

Comment: Here is my debug report:

Comment: Please format this so reviewers can see where each line starts.  If you don't know how to do this, use the help information next to editing a question.

Comment: Did the debugger stop at main.m, line 15 and give you the chance to set breakpoints and explore what is happening?

Comment: okay that should slean it up a bit.. sorry about that. It looks like it did stop at line 15 on main.m. Not sure what to do from there.

Comment: I added some compiler code (not sure if that should be another question) It looks like the storyboard and xib are not being broken down? I have one MainStoryboard with several nibs in it. One xib file and one iPad-Storyboard. -- How do i set break points in the debugger. I deleted all breakpoints i had in Xcode.

Comment: i updated the title by removing the - Black Screen - as it was stated earlier that the No MTP device found has nothing to do with the Black Screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NO MTP Compatible device found] **Solved**  
  
**Solution:**  
1. Connect device to pc using usb data/power transfer cable (some only transfer power not data)  
2. drag down from the top  
3. Click USB connection options 
4. under connect as enable Media Device (MTP)

if you have been messing around in abd CLI you will probably have to kill-server, start-server, double check you device shows up [abd devices -l] before you start running commands on apportable again. Also a good idea before all that would be to do the uninstall, clean device cache, clear app state, etc.

Answer (score 0):

**MTP=no apportable load**. Also run **adb logcat** from another terminal window to look for clues about what's happening.

Comment: odd thing is .. i loaded the app onto a older galaxy s3 and do not receive the NO mtp error. Still the same issue with a black screen though.

Comment: Do apportable uninstall before the apportable load. There may be a problem patching a previous version of the app.

Comment: there are many factors that determine whether or not a device copies using MTP, they are hard to detail here

Comment: at any rate the program compiles and appears to be running, just not displaying.

Comment: then a combination of adb logcat and the debugger are the best diagnosis tools

Comment: thats what I am doing now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: so i found a solution to the no MTP compatible device I will post the answer. However after enabling MTP compatibility, clearing app state, clean device cache and assets, uninstalling and loading I receive: Found (null) (null) ((null)) error; command failed:path to apk

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced similar empty screens.  The presence of "Success" in the output indicates that the package has been loaded on to your test device / simulator.

Also the output:

```
am start -e EARLY_LIFECYCLE_DEBUG 0 -e NSUnrecognizedForwardingDisabled 1 -n corp.laserpros.com/com.apportable.activity.VerdeActivity 
Starting: Intent { cmp=corp.laserpros.com/com.apportable.activity.VerdeActivity (has extras) }
```

is the activity manager starting your app.

It is likely that your app is actually executing but nothing is being displayed.  This happened for me.  Time to start debugging via `apportable debug` or `ROOTED=yes apportable debug` if using a simulator.

In my case, the first issue I ran into was my help screen (a localized image) was not displaying correctly - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275658/apportable-resource-images-are-not-accessible-if-they-have-been-localized) for how I fixed this.

Comment: is this saying that each image resource needs to be in assets/en.lproj/ , or just the splash screen. I have no idea how to implement the code in the link you provided so that it is effective. please provide some more information.

Comment: I added a debug report up above if you would be kind enough to review it.

Comment: I'm not saying the issue I ran into is your problem - just an indication of the types of issues you may run into.  The point was that your application did load and start executing (the message `No mtp compatible devices found` is not causing the black screen).  Also, in the other Q, I'm not saying each image needs to be in `en.lproj`  Instead I'm saying that if they were in that directory (which occurs if you have images localized per language), then apportable doesn't work without a workaround.  The workaround code is pretty easy to follow and shows a one-line summary of how you use it.